# Sum up list in which elements themselves are lists

Tags: list, recursion, sum, scheme, fold

I am having trouble solving a problem, in Scheme, that sums all elements in a list, in which all elements themselves are lists.

I wrote a function `(polyAdd l1 l2)` which takes two lists and sums them together.
for example, `(polyAdd '(1 2) '(3 4 5))` will give `(4 6 5)`.

the code is here:

```
(define (polyAdd l1 l2)
  (cond
    ((null? (and l1 l2))'())
    ((null? l1) (cons (+ 0 (car l2))(polyAdd l1 (cdr l2))))
    ((null? l2) (cons (+ 0 (car l1))(polyAdd l2 (cdr l1))))
    (else (cons (+ (car l1) (car l2))(polyAdd (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))))
```

now I try to write a function `(polyAddList l)` which takes a list of lists and adds them together using my `polyAdd` function. for example, `(polyAddList '((1 2)(3 4)(5 6 7)))` will give `(9 12 7)`, but I have no idea how this should be implemented.

can someone help me? thanks!

Comment: If `l1` and `l2` are zero or longer lists then  `(and l1 l2)` is always `l2`. Eg. `l1` can be `() ` and the first predicate will still be `#f`

Answer (score 0):

1) Can you write a function that adds up a *single* list of numbers?

2) What operation does that function use to combine the first element with the result of the recursive call?

3) Do you have a new operation that you might use to combine the first element with the result of the recursive call on a list of number-lists?

Comment: I can write that function but I'm not allowed. my homework specifies that I have to use the polyAdd that takes two parameters.

Comment: Yes... that's exactly what I'm suggesting! Read my suggestions again.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a `+` operation defined for two operands, `A + B`.

Next you want to define its extended version, `+/`, to work on a *list* of operands:

```
+/ [A,B]  =  A + B 
+/ [A,B,C]  =  A + B + C 
+/ [A,B,C,D]  =  A + B + C + D
```

If only you already *had* this function available to you, you could then use the value

```
B + C + D  =  +/ [B,C,D]
```

to calculate the last two sums:

```
+/ [A,B,C]    =  A + B + C      =  A + ( +/ [B,C]   )
+/ [A,B,C,D]  =  A + B + C + D  =  A + ( +/ [B,C,D] )
```

and in general,

```
+/ [A,B,C,D,...]  =  A + B + C + D + ...  =  A + ( +/ [B,C,D,...] )
```

i.e.

```
+/ [A  ,        B,C,D,...] =
    A  +  ( +/ [B,C,D,...] )
```

which is a structural law, *and* a potential implementation ("structural", because it follows the structure of the *list* data type).

Now you have everything you need to write this down as a valid Scheme code.

*addendum:* and if your sequences were represented by a tree data type (using tree's fringe as a sequence), we'd write

```
+/    [A,B,C,...     ,        O,P,Q,...] =
 ( +/ [A,B,C,...] )  +  ( +/ [O,P,Q,...] )
```

as a law, and use *it* as a guide to another implementation.